# Unload projects before opening the solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I need to open a solution that contains hundreds of projects. However, I only need to have about ten of these projects loaded at any given time. The sheer size of the solution is causing Visual Studio to stall or crash when I take any action with that solution loaded.

I have tried to unload projects, but unloading even a single project is taking upwards of ten minutes. Is it possible to unload projects before opening the solution, or prevent them from being loaded in the first place?

I would prefer to open only the "shell" of the solution, and then manually load the projects I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Funnel extension: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5396fa4a-d638-471b-ac3d-671ccd2ea369

> Decrease solution loading and re-compilation times dramatically by filtering projects not relevant for the current development task.
>
> Large solutions which contain a significant amount of code or projects may be time consuming for Visual Studio in loading and compiling the solution code. In most cases however, we do not need all the source code contained by a Visual Studio solution. We usually work on one or two aspects or features of the application and after completing them, move to the next one. Funnel allows an in-time selective loading of solution parts. It improves the performance for loading and compiling your projects dramatically.

Comment: This turned out to be what I needed. I wish it had a feature that allowed you to select all dependencies, but I was able to load them afterwards.

Comment: There is a checkbox when you open a solution that says "load dependencies"

Comment: This is super. Works like a charm and specially it completely removes the unloaded projects from your solution view is super clean. Loved it!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not really an answer, but I had the same problem with a solution containing 100 projects (OpenSim). VS2013 would spend ages churning over it, freezing up, not responding etc. In fact it was unusable. I uninstalled VS2013 and went back to VS2010 which is much faster. 
I don't think you can just load some of the projects as there are probably dependencies and VS constantly builds in the background so as to give you the right intellisense and autocomplete and highlighted errors etc.

Probably not what you want to hear ;)

Comment: This is interesting to know at least. Are you sure that Visual Studio 2010 is faster and that you don't just have a ton of extensions added to Visual Studio 2013 that make it slower?

Comment: VS2013 express clean install vs VS2010 express clean install. I just could not work with 2013 with a project that size, it takes at least 3 times as long to even open the project and build all its internal references/dependencies than 2010 does. [edit]: This was on a brand new PC too i7 with 16Gb ram and SSD.